# How to use image As data in react

Tags: reactjs, database, image

How do I use image in data type in react

I try using img src in the img data! To get the img store in my folder! To display in the data type

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the img tag with the src attribute set to the URL of the image, if the image is stored in your project folder, you need to import the image into your component first and then use the imported value as the src attribute.

Import the image into your component:

```
javascript
import myImage from './myImage.png';
```

Use the imported image as the src attribute of the img tag:

```
javascript
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={myImage} alt="My Image" />
    </div>
  );
}
```